# "No overload matches this call." message in VS Code when using props in Vue.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I have a Vue.js project that's giving me weird errors/warnings in VS Code:

[image]

- This happens whenever I pass a value as a prop to one of my custom components - it doesn't happen on Vuetify components for example
- It always displays this warning only on the first prop
- It doesn't matter what type the prop is or what you pass to the prop
- The project compiles with no errors, there's no errors in the browser console log either, and my project works just fine
- I use the "regular/default" component style, not the class-based component style
- I use TypeScript

Here's how the prop in the example image is defined in the child element that receives its value:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'MyCustomComponent',

    props: {
        title: String,
    },

    data: function () {},
});
```

How can I get rid of these "useless" warnings?

### Edit

As requested, here are the parent and child component scripts:

App.vue

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <v-main>
            <hello-world :title="title" :heading="heading" />
        </v-main>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'App',

    components: {
        HelloWorld,
    },

    data: () => ({
        title: 'Title!',
        heading: 'Heading!',
    }),
});
</script>
```

HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-row class="text-center">
            <v-col class="mb-4">
                <h1>
                    {{ title }}
                </h1>
                <h2>
                    {{ heading }}
                </h2>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'HelloWorld',

    props: {
        title: String,
        heading: String,
    },

    data: () => ({}),
});
</script>
```

Comment: If possible can you please share your parent component definition.

Comment: those aren't warnings, its type error where you have no pass the correct augment or number of arguments to the expected parameters, you probably need to show both parent, child components and the parameters that you passed in your question

Comment: @RohìtJíndal Sorry for the delay, didn't get to it until now. I added the example code for both the parent and child component.

Comment: @devric Sorry again for the delay, I updated the question with the code for the parent and child components.

Comment: What you shared is not enough to repro. Please create a codesandbox.io replica of your project and make sure it reproduces the bug. I used all the code you posted and I don't see the error, so the source must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your problem originates from the `vue-i18n` plugin.

I made a codesandbox using your code and latest vue-2 compatible stack and I'm not getting the warning.

In conclusion, I suggest you look at the sandbox's [package.json](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-glade-19fpuv?file=/package.json) and update any packages you have and are at a lower version than what's in the sandbox.

It's quite possible you have an older version of `typescript`, you might want to start with it first.

If that doesn't fix it, upgrade `vue-i18n` and also check VSCode for any TS plugins/extensions VSCode might have installed. Try disabling or upgrading them.

---

If that doesn't work, this should fix it:

```
import { TranslateResult } from "vue-i18n";

export default {
  props: {
        title: [String, TranslateResult],
  },
}
```

But again, with `"vue": "^2.6.14", "vue-i18n": "8.27.1"` and `"typescript": "~4.5.5"` you shouldn't need it.

---

If none of the above fixes your problem, try creating a replica of your project on codesandbox.io or on vscode.dev. If you're able to repro it, save and share the link.

---

On the off-chance it might help, here's an older article outlining how cumbersome the marriage between `vue-i18n` and `typescript` used to be a couple of years ago: https://medium.com/js-dojo/manage-vue-i18n-with-typescript-958b2f69846f

Comment: I tried everything you suggested, except for the VS Code extensions (didn't have enough time and I'm not at home right now), and nothing worked so far. I guess the culprit must be one of the extensions. I had some problems with extensions in the past, so I can imagine there might be a conflict between two extensions for example. I've never used CodeSandbox.io before, but I'll try to prepare an example when I'm back home.

Comment: It seems the issue was an extension called "Vue Language Features (Volar)". Disabling it made the error disappear. I guess the replica isn't necessary anymore and wouldn't have helped, either. It seems like I had too many conflicting or unnecessary extensions for Vue.js still installed from when I first started working with Vue.js. I uninstalled everything Vue.js related except for Vetur and Vue 3 Snippets, that should hopefully be enough for Vue.js development with Vuetify and TypeScript. What do you think?

Comment: @Symm, happy to hear my answer helped you sort it out. Ref VSCode extensions, I don't feel I'm the position to advise, as I rarely use VSCode. What I can tell you though is most devs I know stick to Vetur when developing Vue apps with VSCode.

Comment: @hga Thanks for your help, I have one last question though: why did you think Vue I18n was the problem? Even though the screenshot I shared showed me using Vue I18n, the code example I shared didn't include Vue I18n anywhere, and I already mentioned the error only appears on the first prop regardless of the value I pass (so even a regular string would cause an error). Could it still have caused issues?

Comment: @synn, I saw `VueI18n`in the screenshot and this used to be a common problem when using `vue-i18n` with TS: `TranslateResult` is not a valid type replacement for a `string`. So TS needs to be told that `TranslateResult` is, in fact, a string, even when the translation is not found. Previously one would need to do it manually but in newer versions `vue-i18n` does it for you, as it should have from the start.

Comment: i removed the vue 3 language extension, that fixed it. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error `No overload matches this call` when using VS-Code with Volar on a Vue 2 project. I missed the dependency `@vue/runtime-dom` as its stated in the installation description here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar. So make sure you have this package installed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, only within vuex types. It looks like the problem was in the volar + vscode 1.74.

[image]

[image]

I installed the `community vscodium version 1.73` and the problem disappeared

[image]

[image]

Another way to solve the problem, I can suggest adding to `tsconfig.json` rule `"strictFunctionTypes": false`.

But I don't recommend this approach, because it removes important type checks.